# How to click an Element Using JavaScript

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
   WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='action-links']"));
 js.executeAsyncScript(ele);
```

I GET THIS ERROR :
"

Answer (score 1):

Use below code :

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='action-links']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```